# Passing array from main function to other functions in C

Tags: arrays, c, file, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I have a dynamic array of strings initialized in the main function, but I'm not sure how to properly use pointers and send my array to function. In the function_w I want to work with the array and then send it back to main function, and later to use in other functions.
This is my code:

```
char function_w(char **array,FILE **fr)
{
int i = 0, strcount = 0;
int buf_length = 50; 
char buf [buf_length],p = NULL;
fseek(*fr, 0, SEEK_SET);

 while (fgets(buf, buf_length, *fr) != NULL)
 {
    array = (char **)realloc(array, (strcount + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    array[strcount++] = strdup(buf);
 }
return p;
}

int main(void)
{   
    char **array = NULL;
    FILE*fr = NULL; //file is opened in other function, before calling w
...
    if (fr != NULL) **array = function_w(array,&fr);
    else printf("Error");
return 0;
}
```

Every time I use function_w there's no output. Can you help me?

Comment: My c skills are a little bit outdated but shouldn't it be `*fr` instead of `&fr`

Comment: @SimonDanninger No because you usually won't touch the contents of the structure(?) `FILE`. It should be `fr` and the argument should be changed accordingly in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

- To have functions modify what are passed, pass pointers to what should be modified. What should be modified is `char**` in this case, so a pointer to that is `char***`.
- The caller of `function_w` will want the information `strcount`, so you should return that.
- You won't need a pointer to `FILE*` because you don't modify that.

Applying these, your program should be like this:

```
int function_w(char ***array,FILE *fr)
{
    int i = 0, strcount = 0;
    int buf_length = 50; 
    char buf [buf_length],p = NULL;
    fseek(fr, 0, SEEK_SET);

    while (fgets(buf, buf_length, fr) != NULL)
    {
        *array = realloc(*array, (strcount + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        (*array)[strcount++] = strdup(buf);
    }
    return strcount;
}

int main(void)
{   
    char **array = NULL;
    FILE*fr = NULL; //file is opened in other function, before calling w
    int strcount;
...
    if (fr != NULL) strcount = function_w(&array,fr);
    else printf("Error");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I found another problem :( When I want to print my array, it only prints the first item of the array. 'for(i = 0; i < strcount; i++)
 printf("array[%d] == %s", i, *array[i]);'

Comment: @Cassie It is surprising that the code prints the first item of the array. It will cause Segmentation Fault in my view. It is not impossible because anything is allowed on *undefined behavior* though.

Comment: @Cassie Ah, or the code is in the function `function_w`, not `main`? Then use `(*array)[i]` like I did.

Comment: I can't believe the problem was with brackets xD. Thank you again. I'm new to programming so I don't understand pointers yet.